# How to set Unexpected Type in list of None's Python

Tags: python

I am trying to put a Port in a list of None's

```
ports = [None] * 5

for ident in range(len(self.ports)):
     if self.ports[ident] is None:
          try:
              serialC = Serial("COM" + str(ident), 19200)
              portX = Port(serialC, ident, self.main)
              #portX.start()
              self.ports[ident] = portX
          except Exception as e:
              print(e)
              continue
```

But I get an Unexpected type(s)
(int, Port)
Expected
(int, None)
(slice, itarable[None])

With error message: Can't set attribute.

How do I fix this error?.

```
class Port(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, port, ident, main):
        self.main = main
        self.port = port
        self.ident = ident
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\TDJ-PC\PycharmProjects\embeddedProject\serialTh.py", line 28, in check
    portX = Port(Serial("Com" + str(ident), 19200), ident, self.main)
  File "C:\Users\TDJ-PC\PycharmProjects\embeddedProject\port.py", line 10, in __init__
    self.ident = ident
AttributeError: can't set attribute
```

Comment: can you post the exact stacktrakce? (without catching the exception of course)

Comment: Could you share the complete traceback, it would be very helpful to help you?

Comment: I'm confused. Your stack trace says `can't set attribute`. Where did you see `Unexpected type(s) (int, Port) Expected (int, None) (slice, itarable[None])`?

Comment: @Kevin Pycharm show's it as a warning when hovering over the 'ident' in ```self.ports[ident] = portX```

Comment: Your code isn't consistent with the stack trace it supposedly produces. That said, the problem appears to be inside the definition of `Port.__init__` (or something similar), nothing to do with the loop you show.

Comment: I don't think you can assign to a thread's `ident` attribute yourself. If you want to assign unique numbers to your threads, consider using a different attribute name.

Comment: @Kevin okay, that was the answer apparently. Thank you! never knew ident wasn't allowed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ident` property of a `Thread` object is not assignable; you cannot set it from the `__init__` method of your subclass, and it doesn't make sense to do so.

From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.Thread.ident):

> The ‘thread identifier’ of this thread or None if the thread has not been started. This is a nonzero integer. See the get_ident() function. Thread identifiers may be recycled when a thread exits and another thread is created. The identifier is available even after the thread has exited.

So, the `ident` property will be set for you automatically when you start the thread.